# How to isolate spring boot app redis and spring boot session global redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session

As I know, spring boot and spring session provided us one-stop autoconfig, but when my app use session redis and app cache redis not same redis server;
How can I config it, thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, by default, both spring-session and spring-cache are actually configured by spring-boot with a `RedisConnectionFactory` bean named as `connectionFactory`.
Two ways to do this.

1. make `spring-session` to use a different `connectionFactory` bean instance, and leave spring-cache to use the default `connectionFactory`. And below is a sample solution:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class RedisHttpSessionConfig {

       @Bean
       StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer() {
           return new StringRedisSerializer();
       }

       @Bean
       RedisConnectionFactory redisHttpSessionConnectionFactory() {
           RedisConnectionFactory redisHttpSessionConnectionFactory = null;
           // ... add your codes here
           return redisHttpSessionConnectionFactory;
       }

       @Bean
       public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> sessionRedisTemplate(
               RedisConnectionFactory redisHttpSessionConnectionFactory) {
           RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
           template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
           template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
           template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
           template.setDefaultSerializer(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
           template.setConnectionFactory(redisHttpSessionConnectionFactory);
           return template;
       }
   }
   ```
2. make `spring-cache` to use a different `connectionFactory` bean instance, and leave spring-session to use the default `connectionFactory`. And below is a sample solution:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class RedisCacheConfig {

       @Bean
       StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer() {
           return new StringRedisSerializer();
       }

       @Bean
       RedisConnectionFactory redisCacheConnectionFactory() {
            RedisConnectionFactory redisCacheConnectionFactory = null;
            // ... add your codes here
            return redisCacheConnectionFactory;
       }

       @Bean
       RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisCacheConnectionFactory) {
           RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate();
           redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisCacheConnectionFactory);
           redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(this.stringRedisSerializer());
           redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
           return redisTemplate;
       }

       @Bean(name = "stringRedisTemplate")
       public StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisCacheConnectionFactory) throws UnknownHostException {
           StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate();
           stringRedisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisCacheConnectionFactory);
           stringRedisTemplate.setKeySerializer(this.stringRedisSerializer());
           stringRedisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
           return stringRedisTemplate;
       }

       @Bean
       CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
           RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
           cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(600l);
           cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
           return cacheManager;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Mark the default RedisConnectionFactory @Primary

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(RedisProperties properties) {
        return redisConnectionFactory(redisProperties);
    }
```

And mark the session RedisConnectionFactory @SpringSessionRedisConnectionFactory

```
    @Bean
    @SpringSessionRedisConnectionFactory
    public RedisConnectionFactory springSessionRedisConnectionFactory() {
        return redisConnectionFactory(...);
    }
```

redisConnectionFactory() config RedisConnectionFactory.
For example:

```
private static RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(RedisProperties redisProperties, boolean afterPropertiesSet) {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(redisProperties.getHost());
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisProperties.getPassword()));
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(redisProperties.getDatabase());
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(redisProperties.getPort());

        GenericObjectPoolConfig genericObjectPoolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(redisProperties.getLettuce().getPool().getMaxIdle());
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setMinIdle(redisProperties.getLettuce().getPool().getMinIdle());
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(redisProperties.getLettuce().getPool().getMaxActive());
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(redisProperties.getLettuce().getPool().getMaxWait().toMillis());
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);

        LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration,
                LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder().commandTimeout(redisProperties.getTimeout()).poolConfig(genericObjectPoolConfig).build());
        if (afterPropertiesSet) {
            lettuceConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        }
        return lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }
```