# is it possible for spring session redis to deserialize after serialVersionUID is updated and ignore old version

Tags: spring-security, spring-data, deserialization, spring-session

I first created a UserDetailsA for spring session redis with serialVersionUID = 1L,
and then I updated it to UserDetails(properties are different with UserDetailsA) with with serialVersionUID = 2L,
when I start the application it will throw

> local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local
> class serialVersionUID = 2

it may caused by there have complex version in the session

could I make session ignore old serialVersionUID and only deserialize the new one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to isolate spring boot app redis and spring boot session global redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965495/how-to-isolate-spring-boot-app-redis-and-spring-boot-session-global-redis)

Answer (score 0):

solve the problem by change `session:redis:namespace: spring:session:v1/v2/v3`

and I think it can be solved by change spring session redis using `StringRedisTemplate` instead of `RedisTempalte`

which means using `StringRedisSerializer` instead of `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`

but I don't know where to change the default template for spring session redis, if anyone knows, please tell me :)